# Write object toString() to file, formatted neatly in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a polymorphic HashSet that I want to write the toString() of each object in that HashSet to a file so that is is formatted the way it looks when printed to the console. I am able to write everything to the file, but each object is being printed out on one line. I would like to have each object printed the way it's toString() is formatted (every field printed on a new line).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried a bunch of things, but this is what I currently have for my method:

```
public void employeeWriter(String fileName, HashSet<Employee> employees)
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false)));   

        for (Employee e : employees)
        {
            pw.println(e);
        }    
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error writing to file in employeeWriter()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the Employee toString() - Every child of Employee has its own toString() method which prints this toString() plus its own unique fields.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String output = "\n\t--Employee--" + "\nName:" + "\t\t" + getName()
        + "\nTitle:" + "\t\t" + this.getClass().getSimpleName()
        + "\nID: " + "\t\t" + getId() + "\nHire Year:" + "\t\t"
        +  getHireYear() + "\nTax Rate:" + "\t\t"
        + percentFormatter.format(getTaxRate()) + "\nPay Before Taxes:"
        + "\t" + formatter.format(getWeeklySalaryBeforeTaxes())
        + "\nPay After Taxes:" + "\t"
        + formatter.format(getWeeklySalaryAfterTaxes())
        + "\nWeekly Taxes:" + "\t\t"
        + formatter.format(getWeeklyTaxes());

    return output;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra semcolon inside the for loop in try block. typo i believe?

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of the `toString()` method, please?

Comment: hagubear - yes that was a typo.

Comment: Dev - I added the toString() of the super class Employee.

Comment: I get the expected output when I run a simplified version. If you're on Windows and using Notepad, try using a different text editor.

Comment: irrelephant - Wow, thank you. I opened the file using notepad++ and I see that it is indeed working. Something so silly ha

Answer (score 4):

In the `toString` method you are using `\n` as line separators. But if you open a file which uses Unix line separators in program that doesn't support them (eg. Notepad on Windows) the text will appear to be on one line.

The `println` method of `FileWriter` correctly uses platform-specific line separators, which is why your individual employee entries appear on separate lines but not the employee details from `toString()` method, because you are using fixed `\n` line separator there.

So one possible solution to this problem is using correct line separators for your platform in `toString` method (use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) as suggested by Julian Ladisch).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I will try using System.lineSeparator(). I thought about printing each field with the PrintWriter, but then I would have to account for the unique fields that different Employees have, which would defeat the purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: Oh yes, I totally forgot that you mentioned polymorphism in your question, never mind then :), I'll edit that part out of my answer.

Comment: So I just changed all of my toString() methods to implement java.lang.System.lineSeparator(). Is there a way to do something similar for \t? The reason I ask, is I also have this Employee data being displayed on a JTextArea of a GUI and the tab spacing on the GUI appears different than the spacing on the file.

Comment: Tab spacing isn't something platform-specific. It is up to the editor or gui component configuration to determine how tabs are rendered as far as i know. I guess you could use spaces instead if you need fixed size of the indent everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of \n use java.lang.System.lineSeparator(). That way it writes \r\n on windows platforms.